# Chrome Extension: pageAction.onClicked needs to be clicked twice

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm currently working on a chrome extension that uses a `PageAction`. I want the `PageAction` to inject a script and show a popup when clicked. I'm using the following code:

```js
// Called when the user clicks on the page action.
chrome.pageAction.onClicked.addListener(function (tab) {
  chrome.pageAction.setPopup({ tabId: tab.id, popup: "popup.html" });
  chrome.pageAction.show(tab.id);
  // No tabs or host permissions needed!
  console.log(`We're on fire! Injecting script for ${tab.url}`);
  chrome.tabs.executeScript({
    file: 'js-libs/uuidv4.min.js'
  });
  chrome.tabs.executeScript({
    file: 'js-libs/loglevel.min.js'
  });
  chrome.tabs.executeScript({
    file: 'contentScript.js'
  });
});
```

However, I am facing the following problem: Upon the first click, the scripts are injected (as confirmed by `contentScript`-logs), but the popup doesn't show. Every following click then shows the `popup.html` and the scripts don't seem to be injected again.

I would like to have the scripts injected **and** the popup show on the first click. Why is this not happening? Am I missing something obvious here?

Comment: This is the intended behavior because onClicked works only when there's no popup file set via setPopup or manifest.json. The solution is to remove onClicked and specify the popup via `default_popup` key in manifest.json. You'll probably have to rework the extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the help of wOxxOm, I have been able to figure out a solution. Most importantly to note, `pageAction.onClicked` only fires when **no** `default_popup` is specified in the `manifest.json` file or set through the `pageAction.setPopup` function (thanks wOxxOm!).

The solution to having `popup.html` pop up **and** the content script(s) injected, is to inject the content script(s) from within the `popup.js` file. There's a caveat though: `popup.js` executes every time the popup is opened, whereas the content script is persistent (for the current tab's window context). In order to avoid having `popup.js` execute the content script every time `popup.html` is opened, one may stick to the following pattern:

```js
if (typeof scriptAlreadyExecuted === 'undefined') {
    // scriptAlreadyExecuted is undefined, therefore let's execute our content script
    var scriptAlreadyExecuted = true; // let's define this variable in window context to avoid re-executing the content script
    executeContentScript();
else {
    // scriptAlreadyExecuted in window range -> let's skip injecting script again.
    console.log("No need to execute script again. Skipping script execution.")
}
```

An alternative would be to have the extension send a message that the background script listens to, but this would leave the problem of having to make sure that the content script doesn't execute twice.

A good alternative might be to use the `webNavigation.onCompleted`-API in combination with event filters - I haven't tried this yet, as I haven't found out how to use CSS filters with this yet (which is easy with the `PageStateMatcher`-API).

Hope this helps somebody!